# compiler for java

Tags: java

how create a compiler for java using a java program

Comment: Do you mean dynamic compilation or real new compiler?

Answer (score 5):

Since Java 1.6 there is actually a compiler API built into the standard API:

- [Java SE 6 Compiler API](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/12/13/java-se-6-compiler-api/)

You could have a look at these classes / interfaces for instance

- [`Compiler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)
- [`JavaCompiler.CompilationTask`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)

Answer (score 2):

- Understand the theorem on compiler construction
- Implement your own compiler in java. See how [MiniJava](http://www.cambridge.org/us/features/052182060X/) was formed.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a very hard job. My advice: Don't do it. Search for an existing one on the web.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java to build a Java compiler, first you'll need an existing Java compiler. If you have an existing Java compiler, then you don't need to build one in the first place, unless you really want to. In that case, look at other people's answers and know that building a compiler isn't trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can call java compiler from java program with [JavaCompiler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) class.